# I got error while calling the .NET web Service with KSOAP2 in android

Tags: android, web-services

While I run my emulator to call the .NET web service with KSOAP2 in Android.
I know it reads the HTML file but I don't know how to solve the problem.

> org.xmlpull.v1.xmlPullParserException: expected:START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope(position:START_TAG@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4375fda8)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the response is as expected... Usually I get this error when the response contain some error like "not authorized" for example, so the problem should be somewhere in the request. Anyway, I'd check the response InputStream to see if there is the expected response first - 
[StreamToString](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html)